# Loading bookmarklet in a window with disabled Navigation Toolbar

Tags: javascript, gmail

Everybody knows how to run a bookmarklet or some javascript on a window: just click on your bookmarklet, or type "javascript:function(){ etc. }" in the Navigation Toolbar.

But here is the situation. I open a detached window in Gmail, for example a detached window to compose an email, or a separate window for chat. Now this separate window does not have my Bookmarks Toolbar where I store my bookmarklet. And the Navigation Toolbar is disabled: I can not type anything there.

How can I overcome this and still run some custom javascript on this window? Is it possible?

Comment: You can still press Ctrl+L to open the equivalent of the location bar.  Javascript bookmarklets appear to work correctly based on my one attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug or your browser's JavaScript Console (in Chrome on OS X, the hotkey is Alt-Cmd-J, Firefox OS X is Shift-Cmd-J). Hack away.